# How to split a bitmap by a line

Tags: android, bitmap, slice

I am working on a project for android devices. I want to split a bitmap image by a line into 2 bitmaps. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

If resulting bitmaps are rectangular, i. e. line is either horizontal or vetical - you need to use this method of a canvas:

[drawBitmap](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawBitmap%28android.graphics.Bitmap,%20android.graphics.Rect,%20android.graphics.RectF,%20android.graphics.Paint%29)

You just create new bitmaps and use this methods for partial drawing of original bitmaps on its Canvas.

Otherwise - more tricky, I suppose you will need using masks and color blending using PorterDuff alghorithm (all is available through Canvas API) or just clip with a Path.